# Javac Cannot Find Symbol -- Importing errors?

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to compile, and I'm 100% positive I have imported everything correctly.
My error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin>javac LauncherPanel.java
LauncherPanel.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher;
                             ^
  symbol:   class Launcher
  location: package net.minecraft.launcher
LauncherPanel.java:9: error: package net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs does not exist
import net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs.LauncherTabPanel;
                                     ^
LauncherPanel.java:10: error: package net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs does not exist
import net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs.WebsiteTab;
                                     ^
LauncherPanel.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  private final LauncherTabPanel tabPanel;
                ^
  symbol:   class LauncherTabPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  private final BottomBarPanel bottomBar;
                ^
  symbol:   class BottomBarPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  private final Launcher launcher;
                ^
  symbol:   class Launcher
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  public LauncherPanel(Launcher launcher)
                       ^
  symbol:   class Launcher
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
  public LauncherTabPanel getTabPanel()
         ^
  symbol:   class LauncherTabPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
  public BottomBarPanel getBottomBar()
         ^
  symbol:   class BottomBarPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
  public Launcher getLauncher()
         ^
  symbol:   class Launcher
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    this.bottomBar = new BottomBarPanel(launcher);
                         ^
  symbol:   class BottomBarPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    this.tabPanel = new LauncherTabPanel(launcher);
                        ^
  symbol:   class LauncherTabPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    this.loginPanel = new TexturedPanel("/cakehoohoohoo.png");
                          ^
  symbol:   class TexturedPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
LauncherPanel.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
    return new TexturedPanel("/cakehoohoohoo.png");
               ^
  symbol:   class TexturedPanel
  location: class LauncherPanel
14 errors
```

...And here is my .java file:

```
package net.minecraft.launcher.ui;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher;
import net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs.LauncherTabPanel;
import net.minecraft.launcher.ui.tabs.WebsiteTab;
public class LauncherPanel
  extends JPanel
{
  public static final String CARD_DIRT_BACKGROUND = "loading";
  public static final String CARD_LOGIN = "login";
  public static final String CARD_LAUNCHER = "launcher";
  private final CardLayout cardLayout;
  private final LauncherTabPanel tabPanel;
  private final BottomBarPanel bottomBar;
  private final JProgressBar progressBar;
  private final Launcher launcher;
  private final JPanel loginPanel;
  public LauncherPanel(Launcher launcher)
  {
    this.launcher = launcher;
    this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    setLayout(this.cardLayout);
    this.progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    this.bottomBar = new BottomBarPanel(launcher);
    this.tabPanel = new LauncherTabPanel(launcher);
    this.loginPanel = new TexturedPanel("/cakehoohoohoo.png");
    createInterface();
  }
  protected void createInterface()
  {
    add(createLauncherInterface(), "launcher");
    add(createDirtInterface(), "loading");
    add(createLoginInterface(), "login");
  }
  protected JPanel createLauncherInterface()
  {
    JPanel result = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    this.tabPanel.getBlog().setPage("daxsocial.net16.net");
    JPanel topWrapper = new JPanel();
    topWrapper.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    topWrapper.add(this.tabPanel, "Center");
    topWrapper.add(this.progressBar, "South");
    this.progressBar.setVisible(false);
    this.progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    this.progressBar.setMaximum(100);
    result.add(topWrapper, "Center");
    result.add(this.bottomBar, "South");
    return result;
  }
  protected JPanel createDirtInterface()
  {
    return new TexturedPanel("/cakehoohoohoo.png");
  }
  protected JPanel createLoginInterface()
  {
    this.loginPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    return this.loginPanel;
  }
  public LauncherTabPanel getTabPanel()
  {
    return this.tabPanel;
  }
  public BottomBarPanel getBottomBar()
  {
    return this.bottomBar;
  }
  public JProgressBar getProgressBar()
  {
    return this.progressBar;
  }
  public Launcher getLauncher()
  {
    return this.launcher;
  }
  public void setCard(String card, JPanel additional)
  {
    if (card.equals("login"))
    {
      this.loginPanel.removeAll();
      this.loginPanel.add(additional);
    }
    this.cardLayout.show(this, card);
  }
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, it would be very helpful!
I decompiled a .class file, with jd-gui.exe, and then copied the code into a .txt document, edited it, and saved as a .java file. I can't compile now...

Comment: You didnt specify a classpath.

Comment: Thank You!!! I feel stupid...

Comment: That's all part of the learning process. I strongly advise you against using javac, all your building and compiling should be done by an IDE or a build tool such as ant or maven.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the compiler is not finding the class `net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher`. In other words, it can neither find the source file Launcher.java in the source path, nor the Launcher.class in the class path.

Probably you should add the JAR file containing the Launcher.class to the class path (option `-classpath` or environment variable `CLASSPATH`), assuming you have not created/changed this class; otherwise you must adjust the source path (option `-sourcepath`) - see [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Just a note, the `import` is more like a shortcut so you can type `Launcher` instead of `net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher` in your code.